# I'm just getting into multivariate and I'm just confused on some notation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation

If $T: R^2 \to R^2$ is defined by $T(s,t)=\big(\cos(t^2s),\log{(\sqrt{1+s^2})}\big)$, is $T(s,t)$ also the same as $\cos(t^2s)+\log{(\sqrt{1+s^2})}$? If not, then how to I make $T(s,t)=\big(\cos(t^2s),\log{(\sqrt{1+s^2})}\big)$ into something that excludes that comma?

Comment: T is a vector valued function, like stated, it maps $\mathbb{R}^2$ to  $\mathbb{R}^2$. More simply, it takes as input two values and outputs two values. So $T(s,t)$ may not be written as $\cos(t^2s)+\log\left(\sqrt{1+s^2}\right)$, because this would take as input two values and give as output just one, in other words, it would be a map from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. Also, there are different notations to express a vector value function, I believe a fairly used one is by using unit vectors: $\mathbf{e_1},\mathbf{e_2},\mathbf{e_3},...$, or maybe more familiar, $\hat{i},\hat{j}$.

Comment: So, if you are interested in removing the commas, and by this I hope you mean expressing it in a different form, then $T(s,t)=\cos(t^2s)\hat{i}+\log\left(\sqrt{1+s^2}\right)\hat{j}$ may be a possibility. Here the unit vectors point in the $x$ and $y$ direction, respectively. Usually in calculus textbooks, $(\text{something},\text{other something},...)$ will denote a vector.

Answer (score 0):

No, they're different.

To exclude the comma, you could write $T(s,t)=\cos 
 s^2t \bf{i}+\log\sqrt{1+s^2}\bf j$, but now here come the commas again, ${\bf i}{=(1,0)}$ and ${\bf j}{=(0,1)}$.

Or you could write $T(s,t)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos 
 s^2t\\\log\sqrt{1+s^2}\end{pmatrix}$.

So the comma is pretty essential.

Comment: Thanks you for all your inputs! Y'all we're really helpful and now I understand the logic behind my question

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying, $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a function that takes an n-dim. vector as an input and outputs a m-dim. vector. In your example, $T$ maps 2D vectors to 2D vectors.

The other function you're describing can be thought of as $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $F(s,t)=\cos(t^2 s) + \log (\sqrt{1+s^2})$. This function maps 2D vectors to 1D vectors, and 1D vectors are simply scalars or numbers. This is why there are no commas, since your output vector is 1-dimensional.

Does that make sense?